# React.js. How to pass local images dynamicly according to id property?

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem. I don't know how to pass this local images dynamicly.

Lets say I have API which returns static 6 store schema like that.

```
stores: [{id:1, name: "Wallmart"}, {id: 2, name: "Amazon"}];
```

and I have some images called **store1.jpg**, **store2.jpg** ...etc.
So I import images like that.

```
import store1 from "./store1.jpg"
```

So I need to loop these images dynamicly according to id.

```
{
   stores.map((store) => (
     <img src={`store${store.id}`} />
   )
}
```

So, My question is what is best way to do that. maybe I can create some object which contains all images or import all images like that. I didn't check this version maybe it's not working at all. It doesn't looks like proper way. Can someone just advice me something who have experinced with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this type of solution because I figure out that I also have colors. I add all my images into **public/images** folder

```js
export const stores : any = {
    store1:{
        id: 1,
        src: "/images/store1.png",
        tertiary: "#000",
        primary: "#FFF",
    },
    store2:{
        id: 2,
        src: "/images/store2.png",
        tertiary: "#999",
        primary: "#aaa",
    }
    
    ...
}
```

so I import stores and loop like that.

```js
import {stores} from "./constants"    

        {
          store.map((item:any) => (
            <StoreCatalogCard
                  title={item.name}
                  img={stores[`store${item.id}`].src}
                  primaryColor={stores[`store${item.id}`].primary}
                  tertiaryColor={stores[`store${item.id}`].tertiary}
                  light={true}
                />
          ))
        }
```

Comment: This solution has little to do with the actual question. I'm sure it's the right answer for you, but stackoverflow is supposed to be a place where people can search for questions and find answers. How does this answer help anyone other than you? Please edit your question so that it matches the answer you have given.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Yes, you are right. I will change my question.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about importing the images, and just downright use the path to the images in the `stores.map` function.

```
<img src={"store" + store.id + ".jpg"} />
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I answer with another solution. Could you please look at and share your opinion about that ?